# IJVM, what means the numbers next to the method names?

Tags: ijvm, mic-1

I have the IJVM Simulator I got with the download example code. I don't understand what the numbers next to the methods mean.

[First example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iavU0.png)

[Second example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRcyy.png)

I understand that I am calling the `add` method above, but then what are those 3 and 1 next to `add`? Why am I including them?

Or the 2 and 0 for `fak`?

Comment: Where do those samples come from?

Comment: By the way, please don't tag Java. The fact that IJVM was written in java is irrelevant.

Comment: Please include code directly, not screenshots.